# GRANT all permissions on ALL DATABASES and their tables

Tags: postgresql

I doubt myself, this question is unanswered or I am not able to find it. I have a PostgreSQL 9.5 and need to create a non super-user who can connect to all databases and query their tables. Querying includes normal DML (SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP ) kind of. I want equivalent of following MySQL Syntax:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO <USER> IDENTIFIED BY <PASSWORD>;
```

What should be done to give privilege to a user say 'dbuser'  so that it can **connect** all databases and **query** their tables (single SQL Statement).

**Edit:**

It is already known that it can be achieved for a single database in a 2-step manner:

```
psql -U postgres -d <DBNAME>;
GRANT ALL on ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO <DBUSER>;
```

Given the DBNAMES are multiple, Do we need to repeat these 2 statements for every DBNAME. I want to achieve it in a single statement for all DBNAMES.

Answer (score 3):

The connect privilege is granted to the "public" role by default. So you don't need to do anything there, except for checking that [pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/client-authentication.html) allows that as well.

For granting select privileges you need two steps: grant them for existing tables and future tables. For existing tables you need to do this for each schema in each database, e.g:

```
grant select on all tables in schema public to read_all_user;
grant select on all tables in schema second_schema to read_all_user;
grant select on all tables in schema third_schema to read_all_user;
```

Of course you can generate those statement through a SQL query and run them using `\gexec` in `psql`.

If you also want to grant select for all *future* tables, you will need to alter the [default privileges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html) - again for all schemas in all databases.

Note that what MySQL calls a "database" is in reality a schema in terms of the SQL standard (and in the PostgreSQL world). If you only use a single schema in each database (e.g. `public`), then obviously you only need to do this for one schema in each database.

If you were using the most recent Postgres version (9.5 is no longer supported or maintained), you could simply grant the [predefined role](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/predefined-roles.html) `pg_read_all_data` to the user in question.

Comment: I have figured out that its two step process {current & future}. Command <psql -U dbuser -h localhost> gives error <FATAL: database "dbuser" does not exist>.  Connecting by specifying the name <psql -U dbuser -h localhost -d energy> connects it successfully and executing query <select * from TABLE> gives error <permission denied for relation TABLE>. what needs to be done to get rid of these two errors;

Comment: Well the first error can be mitigated by providing the correct target database (as you found out yourself). The second one by granting the SELECT privileges as I described in my answer.

Comment: Thanks. <grant select on all tables in schema public to dbuser;> dont have DBNAME and hence I understand that i need to connect to DB with <superuser>one by one and GRANT permissions to dbuser. I need a shortcut that can do this in one statement;